# Is possible to index a combo box without jquery?

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

i have a simple combo box with mysql data as below:

```
   | ID  |  sub_category  |  category  |
   +-----+----------------+------------|
   |  1  |       1        |  number    |
   +-----|----------------| -----------|
   |  2  |       2        |  number    |
   +-----|----------------| -----------|
   |  3  |       3        |  number    |
   +-----|----------------| -----------|
   |  4  |       A        |  letter    |
   +-----|----------------| -----------|
   |  5  |       B        |  letter    |
   +-----|----------------| -----------|
   |  6  |       @        |special char|
   +-----|----------------| -----------|
```

Is there a way to list it in a combo box with a index? like:

```
      Number
      1
  2
  3
  Letter
  A
  B
  Special Char
  &
```

Only using Mysql and PHP.

Comment: What do you mean, "with an index"? How is jquery involved with any of this?

Answer (score 1):

[**Yes**](https://jsfiddle.net/ao0kwxk0/), just code your PHP+MySQL to produce this HTML.

For your SQL you will probably need to add some kind of sorting/priority column because sorting `category asc or desc` will not get you the order which you show in your example.

```html
 <select multiple style="height:300px; width:150px;">
  <optgroup label="Number">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Letter">
    <option value="4">A</option>
    <option value="5">B</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Special Char">
    <option value="6">&</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your MySQL connection is called `$mysqli`, then

```
$query = "SELECT sub_category, category FROM your_table";
$results = $mysqli->query($query);
$numbers = array();
$letters = array();
$specialChars = array();
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    switch ($row['category']) {
        case 'number':
        $numbers[] = $row['sub_category'];
        break;
        case 'letter':
        $letters[] = $row['sub_category'];
        break;
        case 'special char':
        $specialChars[] = $row['sub_category'];
        break;
    }
}
echo "Number\n";
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number."\n";
}
echo "Letter\n";
foreach ($letters as $letter) {
    echo $letter."\n";
}
echo "Special Char\n";
foreach ($specialChars as $specialChar) {
    echo $specialChar."\n";
}
```

including whatever HTML formatting you need.